# con el valor absoluto y el imaginario obtener el complejo

Tags: python

tengo 2 vectores con valores absolutos e imaginarios

```
ABSOLUTO = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9870, 0.9755, 1.0034, 0.9856, 0.9962, 0.9576 ]) 

IMAGINARIO = np.array([0.0000j,  0.1688j, 0.0832j, -0.0414j, -0.0683j, 0.0337j,  0.0107j, 0.0660j, -0.0726j])
```

y quiero obtener un vector con numero complejo

```
   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.9858 + 0.1680i
   0.9965 + 0.0832i
   0.9861 - 0.0414i
   0.9731 - 0.0683i
   1.0028 + 0.0337i
   0.9856 + 0.0107i
   0.9940 + 0.0660i
   0.9549 - 0.0726i
```

Comment: Basta sumar los arrays, aunque en tu caso no tienen la misma dimensión, quizás un error al copiarlos.

Comment: ya le corregi, pero tu recomendacion es cunado tengo parte real e imaginaria, yo tengo valor absoluto e imaginaria

Comment: Ah, perdón, no lo había leido bien. ¿El valor absoluto es el módulo del complejo? (o sea la raiz de la suma de los cuadrados de la parte real e imaginaria)?

Comment: exacto ese es el absoluto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que el valor absoluto (o módulo) de un complejo es la raiz de la suma de los cuadrados de la parte real y compleja, es decir:

```
modulo = sqrt(real*+2 + imag**2)
```

despejando de esa fórmula la parte real tenemos que es:

```
real = sqrt(modulo**2 - imag**2)
```

Y en cuanto a la parte imaginaria ya la tienes.

Además, ya que numpy permite operaciones vectoriales (que operan elemento a elemento con el vector), puedes calcular todo en una sola expresión:

```
ABSOLUTO = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9870, 0.9755, 1.0034, 0.9856, 0.9962, 0.9576 ]) 
IMAGINARIO = np.array([0.0000j,  0.1688j, 0.0832j, -0.0414j, -0.0683j, 0.0337j,  0.0107j, 0.0660j, -0.0726j])

COMPLEJO = np.sqrt(ABSOLUTO**2 - IMAGINARIO.imag**2) + IMAGINARIO
```

Y sale:

```
array([1.        +0.j    , 0.98565032+0.1688j, 0.99653287+0.0832j,
       0.98613135-0.0414j, 0.97310604-0.0683j, 1.00283392+0.0337j,
       0.98554192+0.0107j, 0.99401129+0.066j , 0.95484397-0.0726j])
```

Como comprobación de que está bien:

```
print(np.abs(COMPLEJO))
```

---

```
array([1.    , 1.    , 1.    , 0.987 , 0.9755, 1.0034, 0.9856, 0.9962,  0.9576])
```